# How to write a test for a service in which beans self-register

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test, junit-jupiter

Problem with correct class setting for tests.

I have the following service structure

My service:

Interface

```
public interface ColumnsFromTableService {
    List<ColumnsDto> getTableColumnsFromSource(DataProvider dataProvider, String tableName);
    DataProviderSourceType  myDataProviderSourceType();
    @Autowired
    default void regMe(ColumnsFromTableFacade columnsFromTableFacade){
        columnsFromTableFacade.register(myDataProviderSourceType(),this);
    }
}
```

Impl

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OracleColumnsFromTableServiceImpl implements ColumnsFromTableService {
    private final DataProviderInsideDao dataProviderInsideDao;

    @Override
    public List<ColumnsDto> getTableColumnsFromSource(DataProvider dataProvider, String tableName) {
        return dataProviderInsideDao.getColumnsByTableNameFromOracle(dataProvider, tableName);
    }

    @Override
    public DataProviderSourceType myDataProviderSourceType() {
        return DataProviderSourceType.ORACLE;
    }
}
```

My facade:

Interface

```
public interface ColumnsFromTableFacade {
    List<ColumnsDto> getTableColumnsFromSource(DataProvider dataProvider, String tableName);
    void register(DataProviderSourceType dataProviderSourceType, ColumnsFromTableService columnsDataProviderService);
}
```

Impl

```
@Service
public class ColumnsFromTableFacadeImpl implements ColumnsFromTableFacade {
    private final Map<DataProviderSourceType, ColumnsFromTableService> implementationMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public List<ColumnsDto> getTableColumnsFromSource(DataProvider dataProvider, String tableName) {
       
        ColumnsFromTableService columnsFromTableService = implementationMap.get(dataProvider.getSourceType());
        return columnsFromTableService.getTableColumnsFromSource(dataProvider,tableName);
     
    }

    @Override
    public void register(DataProviderSourceType dataProviderSourceType, ColumnsFromTableService columnsDataProviderService) {
        implementationMap.put(dataProviderSourceType, columnsDataProviderService);
    }
}
```

For use, I inject the facade in the place I need.

Everything works in the application. When creating ColumnsFromTableService beans, Spring Boot sees the @Autowired annotation in the interface and and registers the service in the facade. But when testing this facade, I can't set it up correctly.

My test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class EasyServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    TablesFromSourceFacadeImpl tablesFromSourceFacade;

    @Test
    void test(){       
        tablesFromSourceFacade.getAllTablesFromSource(new DataProvider());
    }
}
```

When running the test, the facade is successfully instantiated. But the collection with implementations is empty.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVIIG.png)

I am using
Junit jupiter - 5.7.1
Spring boot - 2.4.3

Comment: Its unclear from you question what you are trying to test in your test file. also, what collection are you implying in `When running the test, the facade is successfully instantiated. But the collection with implementations is empty.` ?

Comment: where is `TablesFromSourceFacadeImpl ` class ? what beans is it expecting to be injected ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided to be rough

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class EasyServiceTest {
    
    TablesFromSourceFacadeImpl tablesFromSourceFacade;
    @InjectMocks
    OracleTablesFromSourceServiceImpl oracleTablesFromSourceService;
    @InjectMocks
    OracleColumnsFromTableServiceImpl oracleColumnsFromTableService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        tablesFromSourceFacade = new TablesFromSourceFacadeImpl();
        tablesFromSourceFacade.register(postgresTablesFromSourceService.myDataProviderSourceType(),
                                        postgresTablesFromSourceService);
        tablesFromSourceFacade.register(oracleTablesFromSourceService.myDataProviderSourceType(),
                                        oracleTablesFromSourceService);
    }
    @Test
    void test(){       
        tablesFromSourceFacade.getAllTablesFromSource(new DataProvider());
    }
}
```

UPDATED

The second solution to the problem is to raise either the entire context of the spring, or part of it. But in my case, this did not work, since the services are scattered across different packages, and I would have to raise the entire context, which is heavy.

Comment: can you please add some context why you have chosen this approach so other people can understand it in the future as well?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Nicolas it is not very clear from you post where you need help. also, there is too much noise in the info. I don't see how this post and your answer is helpful to the community.